# Explicit class object needed as first parameter in self implemented classmethod decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, class-method

I was writing a simple implementation of classmethod decorator for a better understanding of both decorator and classmethod. Here is the problem I faced. When I called the class method with an instance of my class, everything was fine, but calling the method with the class object fails with error:

```
>>**TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'**
```

and when I called the method with the explicit class object as parameter it succeed, but a call to classmethod from class object should pass the class object itself as the first parameter, right?

```
import functools
import inspect

def myclassmethod(meth):
    @functools.wraps(meth)
    def wrapper(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        #print(f'obj:{cls}, cls:{cls.__class__}, isclass:{inspect.isclass(cls)}')
        return meth(cls if inspect.isclass(cls) else cls.__class__, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class MyDecoratedMethods(object):
    _name = 'ClassName'

    def __init__(self):
        self._name = 'InstanceName'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self._name!r})'

    @myclassmethod
    def classname(cls):
        return cls._name

MyDecoratedMethods().classname()
#MyDecoratedMethods.classname()
MyDecoratedMethods.classname(MyDecoratedMethods) # This works
```

Comment: "and when I called the method with the explicit class object as parameter it succeed, but a call to classmethod from class object should pass the class object itself as the first parameter, right?" - it should, but the classmethod implementation is responsible for doing that, through the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), and your implementation doesn't do that.

Comment: Thank you, learning descriptor protocol now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what's going on, I removed the `@functools.wraps(meth)` line and then ran:

```
print(MyDecoratedMethods.classname)
# <function __main__.myclassmethod.<locals>.wrapper(cls, *args, **kwargs)>
```

This shows us, that `MyDecoratedMethods.classname` is simply the function you created inside your decorator. And this function knows nothing about the class it is called from.

However, we can override this behavior with [Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). A descriptor "knows" when it is accessed from a class or an instance and, most importantly, can distinguish between those cases (which is how regular methods are created).

Here is a first try:

```
class ClassMethod:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        print(cls, instance)

class MyDecoratedMethods(object):
    ...

    @ClassMethod
    def classname(cls):
        ...

MyDecoratedMethods.classname
# prints <class '__main__.MyDecoratedMethods'> None
MyDecoratedMethods().classname
# prints <class '__main__.MyDecoratedMethods'> <__main__.MyDecoratedMethods object ...>
```

So we see that accessing the class method from the class sets `instance` to `None` and accessing it from an instance sets `instance` to that very object.

But actually we don't need the instance at all. We can implement the logic without it.

```
from functools import partial

class ClassMethod:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        # create a new function and set cls to the first argument
        return partial(self.function, cls)

...

MyDecoratedMethods().classname()
# "ClassName"
MyDecoratedMethods.classname()
# "ClassName"
```

And we are done. Our custom descriptor accomplished two things:

- It prevented the function from binding the instance to the first argument when calling it from an instance of the class (like a function would normally do to become a method)
- It always binds the class to the first argument when it is accessed from either the class or an instance.

Side note: Your approach to check whether an instance or the class called the function is also flawed (`inspect.isclass(cls)`). It will work for "normal" classes but not for meta classes, because then `inspect.isclass` returns `True` for the class **and** its instances.

Comment: Thank you, I got it, new code is well working now, and I'm reading more about "Descriptors".